# Yii2 SwiftMailer on Ubuntu 18.04 cannot connect to CPanel SMTP Server

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, yii2, swiftmailer

I've migrated a website from a CPanel host to a dedicated server. The CPanel host has a working smtp server, which is still being used by the contracting company. When I try to send emails from my server through this smtp server from my server, I only get a connection refused error.

When I tried to send emails via localhost on my PC, it worked flawlesly, with the same options (credentials, port, host) as those in the app on the server.

Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

Edit: I'm using Yii2 framework with the SwiftMailer extension.

Answer (score 0):

Change the email component as follows:

```
'mailer' => [
         'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
          'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
          'transport' => [
              'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
              'host' => 'host url',
              'username' => '<user name>',
              'password' => '<user Password>',
              'port' => 465,
              'encryption' => 'ssl',
          ],
          'useFileTransport' => false,
    ],
```